# Powershell - hash table from an array

Tags: powershell, hash

I have an array in Powershell with the following rows:
1,Tgt,10,Fld
2,XM,8,Fi
3,TX,12,Fi

First column is the row counter, second column is a filter type, 3rd column is a count, 4th column is an Action Type.

I need to create a hash table of the 2nd & 3rd columns.

When I do the following in Powershell, it creates a hash table I can use.

```
$z=@()
$z = {
Tgt = 10
XM = 8
TX = 12
}
```

But, if I use a foreach to attempt to do the same thing, it creates a collection of the collection.

```
foreach ($b in $arr) {
   $z2 += @{$b[1] = $b[2]}
   }
```

Each has 3 elements in it, but the hash table $z is a `{System.Collections.DictionaryEntry,System.Collections.DictionaryEntry,System.Collections.DictionaryEntry}`

while hash table $z2 is a

```
{{System.Collections.DictionaryEntry},{System.Collections.DictionaryEntry},{System.Collections.DictionaryEntry}}
```

$z can be referenced in a foreach by using the $z.Keys, but I can't reference the same thing on $z2. Even though each has 3 rows, $z is an array of 3 rows, but $z2 is an array of 3 arrays of 1 row each. What I want to do is to have $z and $z2 hash table be identical to each other in every way.

I'm sure I am doing something obvious & wrong trying to create this hash table from the existing array, but cannot figure out what I'm doing wrong.   Any suggestions appreciated.

Thanks!

Answer (score 3):

You don't show where you are initializing `$z2`, but with this line:

```
$z2 += @{$b[1] = $b[2]}
```

you are creating a new hashtable with a single entry (key `$b[1]` and value `$b[2]`) and adding it to `$z2`.

Instead, try using:

```
$z2[$b[1]] = $b[2]
```

To create an empty hashtable, use `@{}`, instead of `@()` which makes an array.

Comment: The combination of both things (I didn't catch the bracket vs parenthesis) and the $z2[$b[1]] fixed my problem.  Thank you very much for the assistance!